# How do I trigger SvelteKit to rerender a specific field

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have a `document` object containing fields like `title` and `name`.

When an operation fails, I'm updating the `document` special field `_failures` with the error messages, for example I update

```js
doc._failures.title = {failCode: 404, error: 'document unavailable'}
```

Now in sveltekit, when I display the fields, I check if there's not a corresponding error in `doc._failures`.

My problem is that when I update _failures, Sveltekit doesn't 'realize' I added fields into it, and never renders the failure messages.

I have a component tree I'm providing the root of with `doc`, but I'd like only nested fields to refresh if there's a failure associated to them. For example `doc.contact.email.personal`

Any suggestions?

**NOTE:**
Just if you wonder how my code adds the _failure here's a snippet:

```js
if (result.type === 'failure') {
    const error = JSON.parse(result.data).error;
    console.log("Adding _failure to ", accessor)
    _set(doc, '_failures.'+accessor, { failCode:result.status, error } )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactivity is based on assignments, `_set` is not an assignment.

You could add `doc = doc` afterwards to invalidate `doc`. This will cause any UI to update that uses doc reactively (i.e. if the reactivity chain is not broken that should be enough).

Comment: You are right, something was wrong , it was not rerendering for some other reason (I restarted the server, and it worked). Could you please point me to a doc about the reactivity chain. Actually I have animations in the form of in:fly, and when I add a single item to an array, all items of all arrays start animating.

Thanks for your answer, appreciate that

Comment: Reactivity is maintained e.g. when passing an object through component props or using it in a reactive statement (e.g. `$: value = doc`), it would be lost if the object is used non-reactively, e.g. using a normal reassignment (e.g. `const value = doc`), changes to `doc` would not trigger updates where the other variable is used. Regarding the animation issue, please ask a separate question and provide all the necessary details, including the code.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check that out and eventually ask a separate question